# The type of an element in a constant set can't override the '==' operator, but the type 'LatLng' does

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a constant file containing these codes.

```
const List<LatLng> pointGroup = [
  LatLng(32.82, 124.56),
  LatLng(32.82, 124.53),
];

const List<LatLng> areaPoints = [
  LatLng(32.72, 124.78),
  LatLng(32.62, 124.94),
  ...pointGroup,
];
```

But, the line where `...pointGroup` is gives an error,

```
The type of an element in a constant set can't override the '==' operator, but the type 'LatLng' does.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is [easily reproducible with any class with a `const` constructor and that overrides `operator ==`](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=230ba401ceb29206516056d3fad8d5e1&null_safety=true).  AFAICT the analyzer complains, but the code runs fine, so it might be a bug with the analyzer.

Comment: This is https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42425.

Comment: In the meantime, add `// ignore: const_set_element_type_implements_equals` above `...pointGroup`.

Comment: @jamesdlin  Adding `// ignore: const_set_element_type_implements_equals` removed the error. Thank you!